# Sql CE Calculate rows from same column when rows are filtered

Tags: sql, filter, row, sql-server-ce

I get wrong data because id's are not filtering. Is it possible to get `t1.id < t2.id` for only one vehicle (regoznaka=OS 428-EF)?

```
SELECT
  t2.id, 
  t2.Regoznaka, 
  t2.tocenolit, 
  max(t2.stanjekm) as km2, 
  max(t1.stanjekm) as km1, 
  max(t2.stanjekm) - max(t1.stanjekm) as Kilometara, 
  max(t1.id) as id1  
FROM Gorivo AS t1  

Right JOIN
  Gorivo AS t2 ON t1.id < t2.id 
 Where t2.regoznaka='OS 428-EF' 
 Group by t2.id, t2.Regoznaka, t2.tocenolit, t2.stanjekm
```

Comment: `RIGHT JOIN`, how come? Most people find LEFT JOIN hard enough to understand, and RIGHT JOIN utterly confusing. (I.e. `main table left join optional data` and `optional data right join main table`.)

Comment: You are joining all id's lower than "OS 428-EF" from the left table to the single one (regoznaka='OS 428-EF') on the right. Are you sure that that's what you intended? Maybe you meant t1.id = t2.id? If not, more details of what you are trying to achieve and the meanings would help.

Comment: @jarlh I ned to calculate how many miles car made               http://imgur.com/a/EQMW0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not limiting the rows from the left table.
You need to apply the condition to the left table as well:

```
and t1.regoznaka='OS 428-EF'
```

OR:

```
and t1.regoznaka = t2.regoznaka
```